# Angle between two consecutives 3d vectors

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to calculate the angle between two 3D vectors in python in which the beginning of one vector is the end of the first one.
For example, the vector A start in the origin and ends in the coordinates (300,0,0) and the vector B starts in (300,0,0) and ends in (460,0,-120).
The only way y finded to know the angle is by translating the origin to (300,0,0) and calculating it by using the code below.

```
u=np.array([-300,0,0]) 
v=np.array([160,0,-120])
c = dot(u,v)/norm(u)/norm(v) 
angle = arccos(clip(c, -1, 1))
```

I wanted to know if there is another way to do it.

Comment: Are you interested in the linear algebra aspect? Because that's pretty  much the only reasonable way I can think of. You can compute `-a`, `b - a` programatically instead of manually.

Comment: Thanks, i would try using a plane. Also, i am going to do it automatically as they are several vectors but before doing it i was interested in knowing if there was another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vg`. It works on top of `numpy`. Just install it via: `pip install vg`.

```py
import numpy as np 
import vg

# get the points
origin = np.array([0, 0, 0])
p1 = np.array([300,0,0])
p2 = np.array([460,0,-120])

# define the vectors from points
u = p1 - origin
v = p1 - p2

# calculate angle between two vectors
angle = vg.angle(u,v)

print(angle)
```

This prints out:

```py
>> 143.13010235415598
```